# Is there a C# open-source search application which scales cheaply?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, open-source, load-balancing

I need to quickly replace a listings website which has the following characteristics:

- smallish database (10,000 items, < 1 GB)
- < 10% of the items updated/created/removed daily
- most common activity is searching the whole dataset, returning 1-1000 items
- traffic peaks at 1 million page impressions per day

The scaling strategy for the existing application has been to separate read-only and read/write activity. Multiple slave databases are used for searching and writes are done to a master, which update the slaves using MS SQL Server replication.

Since read activity is more common than write, this has proved to be a cheap way to do database load balancing, without true clustering.

I now need to replace the application - are there any C# open-source applications which scale as neatly as this?

Comment: Are you asking for a replacement to SQL Server or a replacement for searching your existing data?

Comment: replacement for the application which does the searching and updating of data

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, you have a good search strategy that's working, i.e. SQL Server. Replacing the front end shouldn't be a major overhead in your application, C# is suitable as are many other technologies and I suspect with similar performance characteristics. Are suggesting replacing SQL Server with a C# backend? I think you want to avoid re-inventing that wheel and I'd look to replace SQL Server with perhaps MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: are you saying that this is a 3-tier app? Frontend-Data Access-SQL Server?

Comment: sorry, I was trying to be concise but have not put in enough detail. The app to be replaced is not really tiered and the codebase is unknown to the current team, so to replace the presentation layer we really we need to replace the whole thing. What I'm asking is: are there any open-source apps which do data access in this kind of segregated way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it searching for data and storing data are two different business operations. Personally I am a big fan of Lucene.NET for searching and would recommending investigating if it fits your needs. Lucene.NET has a number of pitfalls and writing to the index can be rather slow. In your situation I think you should stick with storing your data in a relational database (I.E., SQL Server) and look at modifying the searching component of your application.

Comment: We ended up going for Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) running on Linux as our search engine with a .NET middle tier for pre-processing and caching. Blazing fast is not an overstatement and the possibilities for faceted search are endless. So far we are very happy with our choice. The Solr repository is read-only as far as the (highly trafficked) public facing app is concerned, with (read/write) user data stored separately in a MS SQL database. I think Solr would have scaled well as a read-write store but this gives us the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [SQL Server Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express). It is free and has a free manager similar to [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio).